# Issue with Ubuntu installed on Mac, El Capitan

Tags: dual-boot, mac, macbook-pro

I'm not entirely sure if this is a serious issue but while installing Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro I was presented with the following string in the field for computer name:

```
Invalid entry length (0). DMI table is broken! Stop.
```

The install was successful and I can boot into both partitions. To dual boot, I installed `rEFIned` (disabled SIP first), then created a partition with `Disk Utility` and installed Ubuntu onto that partition (i.e. during the install only the partition I created was formatted). This error also occurs whenever I try to run `dmidecode`

According to another Ubuntu thread, this is an issue regarding incorrect reporting of memory to kernel. Wondering if I should be concerned about this.

Also, with regards to removing Ubuntu, would it be sufficient to remove the partition that I created for it even though Disk Utility (diskutil) on OSX still recognizes it as the original FAT32 (which has since been formatted to an EXT4 partition for install)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the installer that gives your computer that name, no worry.
You can change it in settings->Details and name of device.

Comment: Yes, I'm just curious as to why its given that in the first place, sounds like a warning for a problem with the install setup.

Comment: It might have something to do with the live-usb or cd. but it is nothing to worry about. It happened to me and I have not experienced any problems

Comment: Me too after 10.11.6, windows 10, astra. During mint 18.1 install only on a mbpr. Weird :)